# How do I retrieve a reference to a subobject using Reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I'm trying to use duck typing using reflection in C#. I have an object of some random type and I want to find if it implements an interface with a specific name and if it does - retrieve a reference to that interface subobject so that I can later read (get) a property value via that interface.

Effectively I need `as` using Reflection.

The first part is easy

```
var interfaceOfInterest =
   randomObject.GetType().GetInterface("Full.Interface.Name.Here");
```

which will either retrieve the interface description or null. Let's assume it's not null.

So now I have an object reference to an object that surely implements that interface.

How do I have the "cast" like retrieval of the subobject using Reflection only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to, simply access the properties of the interface, through the interface type, but whenever you need to pass an instance, simply pass the original object instance.

Here is a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    var c = new C();
    // TODO: Check if C implements I
    var i = typeof(I);
    var valueProperty = i.GetProperty("Value");
    var value = valueProperty.GetValue(c);
    Debug.WriteLine(value);
}

public interface I
{
    string Value { get; }
}

public class C : I
{
    string I.Value { get { return "Test"; } }
}
```

Output:

```
Test
```

If you want to access it much more using names:

```
void Main()
{
    var c = new C();
    // TODO: Check if C implements I
    var i = c.GetType().GetInterface("I");
    if (i != null)
    {
        var valueProperty = i.GetProperty("Value");
        var value = valueProperty.GetValue(c);
        Debug.WriteLine(value);
    }
}

public interface I
{
    string Value { get; }
}

public class C : I
{
    string I.Value { get { return "Test"; } }
}
```

Comment: This for some reason doesn't work in my case - I have some huge inheritance hierarchy and neither `dynamic`s binding nor using `GetValue()` work with the object interface, so I need to get to the subobject.

Comment: There is no such thing as a subobject. Can you post a short but complete example detailing the problem you're having? If you cast C to I you can cast it back, if there was such a thing as a subobject implementing I for C, you could not cast back, and GC would go all haywire. So if you cast C to I, that reference still represents the C object.

Comment: Whatever, I figured out the problem was because I was using a wrong reference when invoking `GetProperty()`. It works as you've described. Thank you.