# Dynamic cast of System.__ComObject

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting, com, type-conversion

Is is possible to cast System.__ComObject to some type, which is known only at runtime?
I have following code

```
Type ComClassType = SomeDLLAssembly.GetType("ClassName");
dynamic comClassInstance = icf2.CreateInstanceLic(null, null, ComClassType.GUID, "License string");
//This will throw exception, because comClassInstance type is __ComObject and it does not contains ComClassMethod
comClassInstance.ComClassMethod();
```

When I will use code bellow, it works fine, but unfortunately I cannot use InvokeMember in my code, because it would be very complicated.

```
ComClassType.InvokeMember("ComClassMethod", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, comClassInstance, null);
```

So I would like to ask, if it is possible to cast "comClassInstance" to "ComClassType" in order to be able to call methods this way comClassInstance.ComClassMethod();

Answer (score 7):

> which is known only at runtime?

That at least part of the problem.  You can only use a cast when you know the type at compile time.  You don't know so you can't write the cast expression.  But it is deeper than that, you don't know the type at runtime either.  `__ComObject` is the low-level wrapper for the RCW, it stores the IDispatch interface pointer.  It says nothing about what methods you can call and what properties you can use.

This is a lower level of typing, it is dynamic typing.  The general term for this is *late binding*.  Which is a try-to-call-it-and-see-what-happens way of interfacing to code that another programmer wrote.  The C# team resisted it for a very long time, static typing is core in the language, forcing programmers to use Reflection.  But no more, by popular demand they added the *dynamic* keyword in v4, giving C# parity with Visual Basic which always supported it.  Instead of passing strings to the Reflection methods you can now use symbols and the DLR automatically uses reflection to make the calls.  Otherwise the exact same programming effort, you have to know the string.

The major advantage of late binding is that it is resilient to versioning, basic reason why 3rd party apis favor it.  But also its major disadvantage, if you don't have a good manual or the version changed too much then you'll get a nasty runtime exception that doesn't tell you anything more than "it didn't work".  The compiler cannot help you get it right, it doesn't know the type.  IntelliSense cannot help you, it can't offer any auto-completion.  Just a bang at runtime and the only way to figure out what went wrong is to plow through the (missing) manual or to talk to the programmer.

Many COM components support both early and late binding.  You need a *type library* to use early binding, it is a machine-readable description of the interfaces and coclasses supported by the component.  It is the exact equivalent of metadata in a .NET assembly.  And performs the same role, with a type library the compiler can now check your code and IntelliSense can provide auto-completion.

Type libraries are usually embedded in the executable file (.dll or .exe), sometimes it is delivered as a separate file, .tlb and .olb are common extensions.  You can use Visual Studio's File > Open > File to have a look inside the executable file, you'd see the TYPELIB node if the type library is embedded.  You then can use OleView.exe, File > View Typelib command to have a look at its content.  And run Tlbimp.exe to generate the interop library.

If you can't find the type library and don't have a decent up-to-date programming manual then only a telephone can help you.  Call the owner or author of the component to get help.

Comment: Nice Novel. Have you heard of QueryInterface? Have you heard of that keyword 'is' and 'as' uses them? The solution here should be calling 'is' in reflection. I am looking for THAT, not for novels

Comment: You are very rude, hard to see the point.  Try to formulate a constructive comment to get somewhere.

Comment: I don't care how it can't be solved, I need to solve it. I did made constructive comment: look after QueryInterface and reflection implementation of the keyword 'is'.

Comment: @Kobor42 You can have `is` with reflection however you cannot have a cast or `as` with Reflection http://stackoverflow.com/q/21673363/57428. How about trying to chain GetIUnknownForObject() and GetObjectForIUnknown() and then using result as `dynamic`?

Comment: @sharptooth would you have wrote this as an antwort, instead of a comment, I would have selected it as chosen as it's most close to what I need.

Comment: @Kobor42 Well, I haven't tried it so I don't know what the answer actually is. IMO it'd be better if you wrote your own answer explaining what actually worked.

Comment: Meanwhile we skipped the problem entirelly. I figured out how to solve if necessary though: Pick a known com object, make an instance for it and cast to object. Then cast it back to known com type using "as". Compile this and open assembly in ildasm. Reverse engineer and done.

Answer (score 3):

Casting is not required to call Method of COM Object.

C# dynamic can be used as (Writing a cast expression is not required before calling)

```
dynamic comClassInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ClassName"));
comClassInstance.ComClassMethod();
var result = comClassInstance.ComClassFMethod(param);
```

OR

Create a Library project in vb.net (Option strict should be Off, Project properties). Do all COM related stuff in vb.net and add reference to this in your C# project.

Declare the instance type as `Object`.

Do a `CreateObject` call for COM component and call the methods as `comClassInstance.ComClassMethod()`

```
Public Class Abc
    Private _comClassInstance As Object

    Public Sub New()
        _comClassInstance = CreateObject("ClassName")
    End Sub

    Public Sub ComClassMethod()
        _comClassInstance.ComClassMethod()
    End Sub

    Public Function ComClassFMethod(param As String) As Integer
        Return _comClassInstance.ComClassFMethod(param)
    End Function 
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "ClassName" is COM-visible, you should be able to cast the returned com-object with basic type casting.

```
Type ComClassType = SomeDLLAssembly.GetType("ClassName");
ClassName myInstance = (ClassName)icf2.CreateInstanceLic(null, null, ComClassType.GUID, "License string");
myInstance.ComClassMethod();
```

Comment: But I don't know ClassName in compilation time but only at runtime, so I cannot use cast this way. SomeDLLAssembly is dll which is loaded dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Oh.. well, then I'd recommend using InvokeMember. I'm not sure if it will work, but you may also want to try "dynamic comClassInstance = Convert.ChangeType(comClassInstance, ComClassType);"

Comment: Unfortunately it is very complicated to use InvokeMember method in my case, but it looks like it is only solution. I already tried to use Convert.ChangeType(comClassInstance, ComClassType); but I'm getting exception, that object __COMObject has to implement IConvertible interface.
Anyway thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: I did some quick testing and your first approach actually should work perfect if your returned object types are com-visible.

Comment: I also thought so, but for some reason, I'm still getting exception, that method does not exists in this object although Invoke method for same object works fine. I'm really confused of this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you're after, and if it is, you'll need to adapt it to the way you're creating instances because I don't really follow where icf2 came from.  However, if you're just trying to cleanup the way that the majority of your code interacts with COM objects, then one approach is to extend the `dynamic` resolution process.  You can do this by inheriting from `DynamicObject` and overriding the `TryInvokeMember` method (there are other methods you could override, but `TryInvokeMember` seems to be the key one).  This method is called on an object when the dynamic dispatcher is unable to locate a method so that you can do some custom resolution.

So, at a basic level (like all great examples I've skipped error handling etc), you could write a class like this:

```
public class ComWrapper : DynamicObject {
    Object _instance;
    Type _type;

    // Create + save type/instance information in constructor
    // You seem to do this differently, so you'd want to change this...
    public ComWrapper(Guid guid) {
        _type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(guid, true);
        _instance =  Activator.CreateInstance(_type, true);            
    }

    // Invoke requested method, passing in args and assigning return value
    // to result
    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, 
                                         out object result) {
        result = _type.InvokeMember(binder.Name, 
                                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,
                          _instance, args);

        return true;  // Return true to indicate it's been handled
    }
}
```

Then, based on [an example which creates an instance of Word, then tells it to quit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/980t1w1t(v=vs.110).aspx), you would use the above code like this:

```
dynamic val = new ComWrapper(new Guid("{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"));

val.Quit(0, 0, false );
```

I think there's a good chance that the dynamic class already does something similar to the above under the hood anyway, so this might not actually resolve your issue.  However, it may get you closer to finding a resolution.  For example, calling a method on a COM object that doesn't support dispatch will report the error through `InvokeMethod`, but will report `Does not contain a definition` when called via a dynamic instance.